# error: concurrency is only available in iOS 15.0.0 or newer

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I am getting this error after adding firebase_storage in my flutter application.

Reproduced output

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'resume(with:)' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer
/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gtfthnpegbpfxycmzhwiohkbdzgd/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:578:23

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'withCheckedThrowingContinuation(function:_:)' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer
/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gtfthnpegbpfxycmzhwiohkbdzgd/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:612:23

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'resume(with:)' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer
/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gtfthnpegbpfxycmzhwiohkbdzgd/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:614:23

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'resume()' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer
/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gtfthnpegbpfxycmzhwiohkbdzgd/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:648:25

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'withCheckedThrowingContinuation(function:_:)' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer
/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gtfthnpegbpfxycmzhwiohkbdzgd/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:643:23

Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileC failed with a nonzero exit code

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
Exited
```